# \renewcommand{\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}} gives compiler error \thefootnote{} cmd undefined?

Tags: footnotes

The subject line says it all - I assume \thefootnote{} is internally defined so this error seems strange.

I lifted the command from here: http://latex.silmaril.ie/formattinginformation/footnotes.html. Note, the command is missing a }, which I added. The result is as expected -- symbols instead of numbers -- but what about the compiler error?

BTW, I want to switch the indexing so that I can use footnotes and endnotes together without getting the indexing mixed up.

Comment: Is that the exact command you're using? The `{} ` are wrong, move the last `} ` behind `\thefootnote`

Comment: @daleif. That's what it said on the website, and you know everything on the web is true! Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: Actually you didn't copy the line correctly (it's still wrong, but has 3 `{` and 2 `} `)

Comment: Thank you for spotting the error, and to bnb for reporting it to me. I have updated the page at http://latex.silmaril.ie/formattinginformation/footnotes.html.

Comment: @daleif. If you read my post again you notice I mentioned the missing }. It's possible I didn't catch it on the copy/paste, but I added it (except in the wrong place).

Comment: @PeterFlynn. Glad to be of some use!! The webpage was very helpful (nice to see stuff from .ie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggested code is wrong:

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
```

should be (the second line below is just to show the proper position of the missing brace)

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
%                         ^
```

and not

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}}
```

as you did.